# assigning closure value to a variable 'Weird JS'

Tags: javascript, algorithm, closures, iife

In summary I have the following code:

```js
let incrementer = (function() {
  let counter = 0;

  let IncreaseCounter = () => {
    return counter += 5;
  }
  return IncreaseCounter;
})();

console.log(incrementer); // function body () => {} 
console.log(incrementer()) // 5 
console.log(incrementer()) // 10 
console.log(incrementer()) // 15
```

`incrementer` doesn't work even though i had it wrapped in an IIFE.

Is there any way to print out `incrementer` as a variable to be incremented each time, without the invocation `()`?

Is there any other way in Javascript to achieve such goal other than that closure approach?

Comment: But `incrementer` returns a function which is why you have to call it.

Comment: @Andy is right. If you want to access the function you might wanna create it like an object, not a function.

Comment: It's possible to do this with object properties by defining a getter. There's no way to do it for ordinary variables.